# Infinite Scroll using JS not working on chrome browser - PURE JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore, infinite-scroll

I'm working on a Blog website, that uses firebase as the backend.

This is the link to my website - https://www.zealforgood.com

I'm using this function to detect when the user reaches the end of the page and fetch-and-load the next items:

```js
//to get next RightSidebar blocks
window.onscroll = function (ev) {
  if (loading) return;
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
    document.querySelector('.load-next').classList.remove('uk-invisible');
    //getting category blocks
    loading = true;
    db.collection("articles").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(5).get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

          let template = `
            some template
            `
          rightSidebar.innerHTML += template;
          document.querySelector('.load-next').classList.add('uk-invisible');
        });
        lastVisible = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
        loading = false;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
  };
};
```

You can find this code at `line 74` at www.zealforgood.com/js/index.min.js

I'm having the same problem on https://www.zealforgood.com/category.html and all other pages, throughout the website, that I've implemented infinite scroll on.

> **THE CODE DOES WORKS IN MICROSOFT EDGE BROWSER, but doesn't in chrome**

Please can somebody help me with what I'm doing wrong

Also, I'm a novice developer, and only understand basic languages like HTML, JS, and CSS.So please help me with a solution in PURE Javascript, as I'm not familiar with jQuery.

Comment: Then you probably have an old version of edge, current edge version is using the same engine as chrome. So if it works in current edge it also works in chrome. Edit: Also try using [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this, place a div at the bottom of your page and whenever it comes into view, you load more stuff.

Comment: Can you please help me on how to do that?